# Removing Shadow Underneath Semi-Transparent UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I’ve been trying to add a drop shadow to a semi transparent `UIView` but the drop shadow is showing up underneath the view. Basically anywhere inside the outline of the view, I don't want to see any shadows. The location icon has no styling.

[image: Example]

```
// Basic Shadow
self.myView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
self.myView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
self.myView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)    
self.myView.layer.shadowRadius = 0
```

Comment: Not quite clear what result you're **trying** to get... Show us what you're doing to create the view - is that a `UIImageView` with a pre-made image? Is that a `UIView` with corner-radius, borderWidth and an image in the center? etc... And... do you want a "solid extra border with space" at the bottom? Or, do you want a feathered shadow? Show us the original image (or the code if it's code), and, if possible, use a paint program to show how you ***want*** it to look.

Comment: Ok, so I might not been as explicit as I should have been (updated). Basically anywhere inside the outline of the view, I don't want to see any shadows.

Comment: Do you want `A` (solid line "shadow") or `B` (actual shadow)? https://i.stack.imgur.com/02FLi.png

Comment: @DonMag either are fine, as long as inside of the view can be transparent.

Comment: The comments here are inappropriate. It's extremely clear what is being asked. Here's one approach https://ikyle.me/blog/2020/calayer-external-only-shadow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use a custom `UIView` subclass with two `CAShapeLayer`s...

For the "shadow" layer path, use a rounded-rect `UIBezierPath` that is slightly taller than the view, so it extends below the bottom.

Here's a quick example...

**Custom View Class**

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    
    public var translucentColor: UIColor = .white.withAlphaComponent(0.7) { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    public var borderColor: UIColor = .init(red: 0.73, green: 0.84, blue: 0.96, alpha: 1.0) { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    public var borderWidth: CGFloat = 4 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    public var shadowColor: UIColor = .black.withAlphaComponent(0.3) { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    public var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 20 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    public var offset: CGFloat = 10 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    
    private let shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    private let topLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() -> Void {
        backgroundColor = .clear
        
        layer.addSublayer(shadowLayer)
        layer.addSublayer(topLayer)
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        var r = bounds
        
        // rounded-rect path for visible border
        let pth = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: r, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
        
        // translucent rounded-rect bordered properties
        topLayer.path = pth.cgPath
        topLayer.fillColor = translucentColor.cgColor
        topLayer.lineWidth = borderWidth
        topLayer.strokeColor = borderColor.cgColor
        
        // rounded-rect path for "shadow" border
        r.size.height += offset
        let spth = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: r, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
        
        shadowLayer.path = spth.cgPath
        shadowLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shadowLayer.lineWidth = borderWidth
        shadowLayer.strokeColor = shadowColor.cgColor
    }
    
}
```

**Example Controller Class**

```
class CustomViewTestVC: UIViewController {

    let gradView = BasicGradientView()
    
    let customView = CustomView()
    
    // let's add a label between the gradient view and the custom view
    //  so we can confirm it's translucent
    let testLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.textColor = .systemBlue
        v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 34.0, weight: .bold)
        v.text = "This is a test to confirm that the view and the \"shadow\" are both translucent while the border is opaque." // Tap anywhere to toggle this label's visibility."
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        [gradView, testLabel, customView].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            gradView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            gradView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 312.0),
            gradView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gradView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0),
            gradView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            
            testLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gradView.widthAnchor, constant: -4.0),
            testLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gradView.heightAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            testLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gradView.centerXAnchor),
            testLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gradView.centerYAnchor),

            customView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gradView.widthAnchor, constant: -90.0),
            customView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gradView.heightAnchor, constant: -90.0),
            customView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gradView.centerXAnchor),
            customView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gradView.centerYAnchor),
            
        ])
        
        gradView.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        
        gradView.colors = [
            .red, .yellow, .cyan,
        ]

    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        testLabel.isHidden.toggle()
    }
    
}
```

**Basic Gradient View**

```
class BasicGradientView: UIView {
    public var colors: [UIColor] = [.white, .black] { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    public var startPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0) { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    public var endPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0) { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }

    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAGradientLayer.self
    }
    private var gLayer: CAGradientLayer {
        return self.layer as! CAGradientLayer
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() {
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        gLayer.colors = colors.compactMap( {$0.cgColor })
        gLayer.startPoint = startPoint
        gLayer.endPoint = endPoint
    }
}
```

This is the output -- tap anywhere to toggle the `UILabel` visibility:

[image] [image]

Then add your imageView on top (or as a subview of the custom view):

[image]

---

**Edit** *- to answer comment*

We can get a shadow to show only on the outside by:

- replacing the "fake-shadow shape layer" with a `CALayer`
- using the bezier path as the layer's `.shadowPath`
- creating a bezier path with a "hole" cut in it
- use that path as a `CAShapeLayer` path
- and then masking the shadow layer with that `CAShapeLayer`

Like this:

[image] [image]

Here are updates to the above code as examples. Both classes are very similar, with the same custom properties that can be changed from their defaults. I've also added a `UIImageView` as a subview, to produce this output:

[image]

as before, tapping anywhere will toggle the `UILabel` visibility:

[image]

**CustomViewA Class**

```
class CustomViewA: UIView {
    
    public var translucentColor: UIColor = .white.withAlphaComponent(0.5) { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    public var borderColor: UIColor = .init(red: 0.739, green: 0.828, blue: 0.922, alpha: 1.0) { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    public var borderWidth: CGFloat = 4 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    public var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 20 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    
    public var shadowColor: UIColor = .black.withAlphaComponent(0.3) { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    public var shadowOpacity: Float = 0.3
    public var shadowOffset: CGSize = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 8.0) { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    
    // shadowRadius is not used, but this allows us to treat both CustomViewA and CustomViewB the same
    public var shadowRadius: CGFloat = 0 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }

    public var image: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            imageView.image = image
        }
    }
    private let imageView = UIImageView()
    
    private let shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    private let topLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() -> Void {
        backgroundColor = .clear
        
        layer.addSublayer(shadowLayer)
        layer.addSublayer(topLayer)
        
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(imageView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5),
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0),
            imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
            imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
        ])
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        var r = bounds
        
        // rounded-rect path for visible border
        let pth = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: r, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
        
        // translucent rounded-rect bordered properties
        topLayer.path = pth.cgPath
        topLayer.fillColor = translucentColor.cgColor
        topLayer.lineWidth = borderWidth
        topLayer.strokeColor = borderColor.cgColor
        
        // rounded-rect path for "shadow" border
        r.size.height += shadowOffset.height
        let spth = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: r, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
        
        shadowLayer.path = spth.cgPath
        shadowLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shadowLayer.lineWidth = borderWidth
        shadowLayer.strokeColor = shadowColor.cgColor
    }
    
}
```

**CustomViewB Class**

```
class CustomViewB: UIView {
    
    public var translucentColor: UIColor = .white.withAlphaComponent(0.5) { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    public var borderColor: UIColor = .init(red: 0.739, green: 0.828, blue: 0.922, alpha: 1.0) { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    public var borderWidth: CGFloat = 4 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    public var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 20 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    
    public var shadowColor: UIColor = .black { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    public var shadowOpacity: Float = 0.7
    public var shadowOffset: CGSize = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 10.0) { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    public var shadowRadius: CGFloat = 6 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    
    public var image: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            imageView.image = image
        }
    }
    private let imageView = UIImageView()
    
    private let shadowLayer = CALayer()
    private let topLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() -> Void {
        backgroundColor = .clear
        
        layer.addSublayer(shadowLayer)
        layer.addSublayer(topLayer)
        
        // add a square (1:1) image view, 1/2 the width of self
        //  centered horizontally and vertically
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(imageView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5),
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0),
            imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
            imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
        ])
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        // rounded-rect path for visible border
        let pth = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
        
        // translucent rounded-rect bordered properties
        topLayer.path = pth.cgPath
        topLayer.fillColor = translucentColor.cgColor
        topLayer.lineWidth = borderWidth
        topLayer.strokeColor = borderColor.cgColor
        
        // we're going to mask the shadow layer with a "cutout" of the rounded rect
        //  the shadow is going to spread outside the bounds,
        //  so the "outer" path needs to be larger
        //  we'll make it plenty large enough
        let bpth = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds.insetBy(dx: -bounds.width, dy: -bounds.height))
        bpth.append(pth)
        bpth.usesEvenOddFillRule = true
        
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.fillRule = .evenOdd
        maskLayer.path = bpth.cgPath
        shadowLayer.mask = maskLayer
        
        shadowLayer.shadowPath = pth.cgPath
        shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
        shadowLayer.shadowColor = shadowColor.cgColor
        shadowLayer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
        shadowLayer.shadowOffset = shadowOffset
    }
    
}
```

**Example Controller Class** *- uses the `BasicGradientView` class above*

```
class CustomViewTestVC: UIViewController {

    let gradViewA = BasicGradientView()
    let gradViewB = BasicGradientView()

    let customViewA = CustomViewA()
    let customViewB = CustomViewB()

    // let's add a label between the gradient view and the custom view
    //  so we can confirm it's translucent
    let testLabelA: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.textColor = .systemRed
        v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 32.0, weight: .regular)
        return v
    }()

    let testLabelB: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        return v
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        [gradViewA, gradViewB, testLabelA, testLabelB, customViewA, customViewB].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            gradViewA.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            gradViewA.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0),
            gradViewA.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gradViewA.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0),
            gradViewA.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            
            testLabelA.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gradViewA.widthAnchor, constant: -4.0),
            testLabelA.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gradViewA.heightAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            testLabelA.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gradViewA.centerXAnchor),
            testLabelA.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gradViewA.centerYAnchor),

            customViewA.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gradViewA.widthAnchor, constant: -84.0),
            customViewA.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gradViewA.heightAnchor, constant: -84.0),
            customViewA.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gradViewA.centerXAnchor),
            customViewA.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gradViewA.centerYAnchor),
            
            gradViewB.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gradViewA.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            gradViewB.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gradViewA.widthAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            gradViewB.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gradViewB.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0),
            gradViewB.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            
            testLabelB.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testLabelA.widthAnchor, constant: -0.0),
            testLabelB.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testLabelA.heightAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            testLabelB.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gradViewB.centerXAnchor),
            testLabelB.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gradViewB.centerYAnchor),
            
            customViewB.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customViewA.widthAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            customViewB.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customViewA.heightAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            customViewB.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gradViewB.centerXAnchor),
            customViewB.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gradViewB.centerYAnchor),
            
        ])
        
        // let's setup the gradient views the same
        gradViewA.colors = [
            .init(red: 0.242, green: 0.591, blue: 0.959, alpha: 1.0),
            .init(red: 0.113, green: 0.472, blue: 0.866, alpha: 1.0)
        ]
        gradViewA.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)

        gradViewB.colors = gradViewA.colors
        gradViewB.endPoint = gradViewA.endPoint

        // let's give the two test labels the same properties
        testLabelB.numberOfLines = testLabelA.numberOfLines
        testLabelB.textAlignment = testLabelA.textAlignment
        testLabelB.textColor = testLabelA.textColor
        testLabelB.font = testLabelA.font
        
        let s = "This is a test to confirm that the view and the \"shadow\" are both translucent while the border is opaque."
        testLabelA.text = "CustomViewA\n" + s
        testLabelB.text = "CustomViewB\n" + s

        // set the .image property of both custom views
        if let img = UIImage(named: "marker") {
            customViewA.image = img
            customViewB.image = img
        } else {
            if let img = UIImage(systemName: "mappin.and.ellipse")?.withTintColor(.white, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal) {
                customViewA.image = img
                customViewB.image = img
            }
        }

    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        testLabelA.isHidden.toggle()
        testLabelB.isHidden.toggle()
    }
    
}
```

Comment: That looks great. How would you do it also for the spread shadow like in the second pic here. i.stack.imgur.com/02FLi.png

Comment: @TylerRutt - see the **Edit** to my answer. I ***strongly recommend*** you research `layer.shadowPath` and `layer.mask` and try to do it on your own, *before* examining this example code.

Comment: Appreciate the advice & answers. I'll definitely do some more research and get more familiar with masks.